# Git deploy hook ec2 with submodules

Tags: git, node.js, amazon-ec2, git-submodules, supervisord

I created instance on aws running a node application. I installed supervisord to keep the node application up and running. Deployment takes place trough git with a deploment hook.\

The structure is like this:

```
    --- root
      |
      |--repo |-- hooks
      |       |-- branches
      |       |-- etc.
      |
      |--app
```

The post-receive hook looks like this.

```
    #!/bin/sh
    GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/ubuntu/app
    GIT_DIR=/home/ubuntu/repo
    export GIT_WORK_TREE
    export GIT_DIR

    git checkout -f

    echo 'Update sub modules.'
    git submodule init && git submodule sync && git submodule update

    echo 'Install dependencies.'
    cd $GIT_WORK_TREE && sudo rm -rf node_modules && sudo npm install

    echo 'Restart app'
    sudo supervisorctl restart node
```

Every thing works nice, but sinds i'm start using a submodule in my repo, i'm not able to pull the module and got this message. And got this message:

*You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree.*

My installation is based on http://cuppster.com/2011/05/12/diy-node-js-server-on-amazon-ec2/

My config setting

```
    core.repositoryformatversion=0
    core.filemode=true
    core.bare=false
    core.worktree=/home/ubuntu/app
    receive.denycurrentbranch=ignore
```

How can i fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!!